# Creating objects that implement JpaRepo interfaces via Autowiring in JUnit?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit, spring-data-jpa, autowired

I'm tasked with writing JUnit classes. To do this, I need to create an object that implements an interface that extends *org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository*, (called "KanjiRepo") yet no classes in this application actually implement *KanjiRepo*.

Rather than with **new**, all objects that implement *KanjiRepo* seem to be created via **@Autowiring**.

The *KanjiRepo* interface is a member of a package that has only interfaces, and they all extend *org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository*.

[**question**] I don't think I understand the problem. Can someone tell me if what I just said sounds correct. In my junit, do I also use @Autowire to create objects that implement the interfaces in the same package as *KanjiRepo*?Maintaining 2 separate *Application Contexts* will be needed as a last step?

Comment: Spring Data creates an implementation of any configured repository interfaces at runtime. If your tests are running in a Spring context then you simply need to use `@Autowired SomeRepoInterface` to have the generated implementation injected when your test executes.

Answer (score 0):

I think Autowiring KanjiRepo is enough in your test class unless you annotate your repository as @Repository.

```
@Repository
public interface KanjiRepo extends JpaRepository....
```

If you have **@Repository** annotation on top of **KanjiRepo** and if you annototated your main class or configuration class to auto scan beans; spring would handle creating and autowiring beans succesfully.

Please check for component scan

```
@SpringBootApplication
// or  @ComponentScan
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

And then, you can create your test class with the following code;

```
@Autowired
KanjiRepo repo;

@Test
public void testFindById() {
    Kanji instance = repo.findById(0L);
    assert.....
}
```

should be fine.

> Can the application and JUnit share the same configuration files?

Actually, it is. But, if you do component scan, you don't have to worry that. Spring will handle where your bean is and it should autowire succesfully.

> > do I also use @Autowire to create objects that implement the interfaces in the same package as KanjiRepo?

Spring will do component scan and will find where your repository is, so, you don't have to worry that where you locate your repository.